# Can AWS S3 Lifecycles rules be created with a certain date of expiration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, lifecycle

For example, if you were creating a service that stores images that are associated with real-life events, is there a way to set a lifecycle rule to transition/expire objects after the event's end date? In this case, using an expiration rule of 30, 60, 90 days after creation would not be as effective as a set date.

Comment: No, you would have to create some custom solution to do this.

Comment: So would just intelligent-tiering be the best available solution?